# How to parse byte array into HttpRequest (netty)?

Tags: java, http, netty

I'm using netty and need to convert a `byte[]` (representing the complete request, not just the body) into `io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest`. I found [HttpObjectDecoder](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpObjectDecoder.html), but no way to parse it without a socket.

Comment: The `byte[]` is the entire request or just the payload?

Comment: Updated my question - the complete request was meant (from status line to body)

Comment: What netty version are you using?

Comment: I'm using netty 4.1.94